# How to create Mongoose Schema for $near query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have create a collection on MongoDB with with geo index "2dsphere" and I have an element with this structure in my colelction:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("573b2416130380fbf20c2610"), 
    "location" : { 
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ] 
    }, 
    "marca" : "smart", 
    "stato" : "libera" 
}
```

How can I create a schema in mongoose for this strucuture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the collection is named Location, you could either define your schema as:

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    marca: { type: String, required: true }, 
    stato: { type: String, required: true }, 
    loc: {
        type: {
            type: "String",
            required: true,
            enum: ['Point', 'LineString', 'Polygon'],
            default: 'Point'
        },
        coordinates: [Number]
    }
});

locationSchema.index({'loc': '2dsphere'});
var Location = mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

or with the [index](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-index):

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    marca: { type: String, required: true }, 
    stato: { type: String, required: true }, 
    loc: {
        type: {
            type: "String",
            required: true,
            enum: ['Point', 'LineString', 'Polygon'],
            default: 'Point'
        },
        coordinates: [Number],
        index: { type: '2dsphere', sparse: true }
    }
});
var Location = mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```